# How to use postgres version 14 in frappe/helm since they already added the postgres version 15 in thier helm chart?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, erpnext, frappe

The Postgres 15 is not Compatible with frappe 14 version. I have to Deploy a Custom App on Frappe.Since the postgres 15 is Causing problems so I read in requirements you have to use version less then 14 my question how i change the postgres version in order to Deploy

[They already added the zip file of Postgress.My question is there any made to modify this version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlVZa.png)